# Trying to create simple template sum of container

Tags: templates, stl, iterator

I'm just trying to create a simple sum function template to find the sum of doubles within a container using STL. First I'm just trying to test this with a list, but I keep getting an error on line 28.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
double Sum(typename T& container)
{// sum of a container with doubles
    typename T::const_iterator iterator_begin = container.begin();
    typename T::const_iterator iterator_end = container.end();

    double my_sum = 0;

    for (iterator_begin; iterator_begin != iterator_end; iterator_begin++)
        my_sum += iterator_begin->second; // this is line 28

        return my_sum;
}

int main()
{
    list<double> test_list(10,5.1); // create a list of size 10 with values 5.1

    cout << Sum(test_list) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get two compiler errors:

> c:\users...\iterators.cpp(28): error C2839: invalid return type
>   'const double *' for overloaded 'operator ->'
>
> c:\users...\iterators.cpp(28): error C2039: 'second' : is not a
>   member of 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'

Even if I change from const_iterator to iterator, I still receive a similar error,

> error C2839: invalid return type 'double *' for overloaded 'operator
>   ->'

Am I using the pointers wrong here or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STL lists don't support the concept of 'second'. They are simple sequences. This appears to have originally be tailored for a std::map<>. That being said, if a list, vector, queue, etc is your target containers, then:

change this:

```
my_sum += iterator_begin->second;
```

to this:

```
my_sum += *iterator_begin;
```

and it will work the way you apparently want it. There *are* built-in algorithms for doing this kind of thing in STL (for_each, etc...) and you should consider those as potential alternatives.

EDIT: OP asked for how to specialize a summation for both a simple sequence and a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// general summation
template<typename T>
double Sum(const T& container)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    typename T::const_iterator it = container.begin();
    while (it != container.end())
        result += *it++;
    return result;
}

// specialized for a map of something-to-double
template<typename Left>
double Sum(const map<Left,double>& themap)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    typename map<Left,double>::const_iterator it = themap.begin();
    while (it != themap.end())
        result += (it++)->second;
    return result;
}

// a list of doubles.
typedef list<double> DblList;

// a map of int to double
typedef map<int, double> MapIntToDbl;

// and just for kicks, a map of strings to doubles.
typedef map<string, double> MapStrToDbl;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DblList dbls;
    dbls.push_back(1.0);
    dbls.push_back(2.0);
    dbls.push_back(3.0);
    dbls.push_back(4.0);
    cout << "Sum(dbls) = " << Sum(dbls) << endl;

    MapIntToDbl mapdbls;
    mapdbls[1] = 1.0;
    mapdbls[2] = 2.0;
    mapdbls[3] = 3.0;
    mapdbls[4] = 4.0;
    mapdbls[5] = 5.0;
    cout << "Sum(mapdbls) = " << Sum(mapdbls) << endl;

    MapStrToDbl mapdbls2;
    mapdbls2["this"] = 1.0;
    mapdbls2["is"] = 2.0;
    mapdbls2["another"] = 3.0;
    mapdbls2["map"] = 4.0;
    mapdbls2["sample"] = 5.0;
    cout << "Sum(mapdbls2) = " << Sum(mapdbls2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How could I make this work for std::map<>? i.e., I want to create an overloaded function for map as well. So, I'll leave line 28 the same and change "double Sum(typename T& container)" to "double Sum(typename map<string, T>& container)"? I'm running into some errors there as well. Should I post that in another thread?

Comment: It is because of how your summation template accesses the container that your error ensues. A specialization for your case may be required, but I stress again, <algorithm> has a plethora of fantastic container operation functions that can do virtually all of this for you. Start with std::for_each and see how it works closely.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have a homework assignment that specifies that I write overloaded sum functions using stl iterators.

Comment: Well you have the first one nailed down, the second is just a specialization of the first, with the container type being specified as an abstract map of something-to-double. I'll update the answer with a sample of how you can do this. It isn't the only way, and I'm just going to slam it out, but take a look.